Are they called "cardinal" subspaces? If not, what else?
A Cartesian coordinate system for an N-dimensional space S has, obviously, N axes. However, it also has $\tbinom{N}{2}$ planes spanned by those axes, and $\tbinom{N}{3}$ 3D spaces likewise spanned, etc, all the way up to the $\tbinom{N}{N}=1$, say one, hyperspace of N dimensions S that this tyrade began with.
Is there a name for those subspaces - as opposed to the infinitely many linear manifolds of dimensionality from 1 to $N-1$ criscrossing S at arbitrary angles and offsets? Should I call them "cardinal" subspaces, like there are cardinal points on the compass?
In simpler words: in the 3D coordinate system XYZ we all know and love, is there a name for the planes XY, YZ, and XZ, as opposed to, say, the plane $X + Y + Z = 5$?

They are usually called "coordinate linear subspaces" or just "coordinate subspaces."

The word "cardinal" in mathematics usually refers to something completely different and you should not use it in the context of linear subspaces of $\mathbb R^n$. Also, do not use the terminology "manifold" here since it is misleading as well. The usual terminology is "coordinate subspaces" or, if you want to be more precise, "coordinate linear subspaces." The correct definition is:
Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector spaces with a basis $\{e_1,...,e_n\}$. Then coordinate subspaces of $V$ are linear subspaces $W\subset V$ of the form $W=Span(S)$, for subsets $S\subset  \{e_1,...,e_n\}$.
For instance, when $S$ consists of $n-1$ elements, $Span(S)$ is called a coordinate hyperplane in $V$. When $S$ consists of one element, $Span(S)$ is called a coordinate line in $V$.
